# limit of $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left | \cos x \right |$ using squeeze theorem?

Tags: calculus

So when trying to find $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left | \cos x \right |$ my first thought is that the limit doesn't exist since it's an oscillating function, meaning $x$ never trends toward any single value.

But then... I saw something like this on another site, and made me wonder, is it really zero after all?
$$\frac{0}{x}\leq \frac{\cos x}{x}\leq\frac{1}{x}\ \ and \ \ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{0}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{x}=0\ \ \therefore \ \ by\ squeeze\ theorem, \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\cos x}{x}=0$$

Comment: Well, which limit are you trying to find?

Comment: @Saunders Good question.  It never occurred to me that the OP (i.e. original poster) might have a typo in his title.  So, a case could be made that the interpretation in my answer **luckily** proved to be correct.

Comment: Edited for clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly,

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x} = 0. \tag1 $$

An alternative demonstration of that is that in (1) above, the numerator is bounded between $-1$ and $1$, while the denominator grows, without bound.

However, the above conclusion is not relevant with respect to evaluating (if it exists)

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} |\cos(x)|. \tag2 $$

As you first indicated, the expression in (2) above oscillates between $0$ and $1$, and so the limit can not exist.

In (1) above, this oscillation of the numerator, which is bounded between $1$ and $-1$ is **irrelevant**, because the denominator in (1) above is growing without bound.